# Replace all with case Insensitive considering work boundaries in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a jquery code that will replace all words considering word boundaries and is case insensitive.

The code is:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b" + wordList[i] + "\\b", 'gi');
blog = blog.replace(re, 'value to replace');
```

The problem is i want to do the same in **C#** too.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, what do you have so far?  We'll help you with it.  We won't do it for you.

Comment: I am implement the code in jquery but i  need to do exactly the same in c# too. The problem is i know about Replace function and have some knowledge of regex replace but i dont know hot to taken account of word boundaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
blog = Regex.Replace(blog, "\\b" + wordlist[i] + "\\b", "value to replace", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is two clicks away from here (google)...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
blog = Regex.Replace(blog, "\\b" + wordlist[i] + "\\b", "value to replace",RegexOptions.IgnorCase);
```